# Русские символы при вводе и выводе на C++

Tags: локализация, символы, c++

Начал изучать C++ и столкнулся с проблемой вывода русских букв в консоль. У нас на форуме узнал, что чтобы C++ правильно отображались русские буквы, надо применять `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")` и применял её, всё было нормально, пока в книге не прочитал про ввод строк и строки и запустил пример из книги... В программе, код которой идёт ниже, если оставить `setlocale`, то программа выводит русские буквы нормально, а вот если запросить строку и ввести русские буквы, а потом вывести их, то они портятся при последующем выводе. Если убрать `setlocale`, то русские буквы при вводе, а потом выводе не портятся, зато вывод их из программы портится.

```
// insrtl.cpp -- чтение более одной строки 
#include <iostream> 
int main(){ 
   using namespace std; 
   setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
   const int ArSize = 20; 
   char name[ArSize]; 
   char dessert[ArSize]; 
   cout << "Введите свое имя: \n"; 
   cin >> name; 
   cout << "Введите свой любимый десерт: \n"; 
   cin >> dessert; 
   cout << "У меня есть вкусный " << dessert; 
   cout << " для вас, " << name << ". \n";
   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}
```

***Вопрос:*** как мне поступить, чтобы можно было и из программы русские буквы выводить  и при запросе ввода и последующем выводе они не портились?

***UPD***: попробовал так:

```
// insrtl.cpp -- чтение более одной строки 
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h>

char *Rus(char *str)
{
    static char s[1024];
    CharToOem(str, s);
    return s;
}
int main(){ 
   using namespace std; 
   const int ArSize = 20; 
   char name[ArSize]; 
   char dessert[ArSize]; 
   cout << Rus("Введите свое имя: \n"); 
   cin >> name; 
   cout << Rus("Введите свой любимый десерт: \n"); 
   cin >> dessert; 
   cout << Rus("У меня есть вкусный ") << Rus(dessert); 
   cout << Rus(" для вас, ") << Rus(name) << ". \n";
   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
}
```

Но вообще получается что-то странное похоже что в переменные записываются выводимые строки :  в `desert` записывается `"У меня есть вкусный "` а в `name` записывается `" для вас, "`. И что делать я хочу русский язык а не

```
C:\Users\Rules>"D:\ProjectsC++\C++ Learning\Chapter 4\insrt1\insrt1.exe"
Введите свое имя:
Иван
Введите свой любимый десерт:
Какао
У меня есть вкусный ? Є R для вас, ?ў -.
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

после моего кода и не то что стало после UPD а именно:

```
C:\Users\Rules>"D:\ProjectsC++\C++ Learning\Chapter 4\insrt1\insrt1.exe"
Введите свое имя:
Иван
Введите свой любимый десерт:
Какао
У меня есть вкусный У меня есть вкусный  для вас,  для вас, .
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

***UPD***: Нашёл самый лучший идеальный вариант [здесь](http://kpolyakov.narod.ru/school/c/faq.htm) и всем настоятельно рекомендую использовать ТОЛЬКО ЭТОТ ВАРИАНТ он самый лучший!

Comment: проблема относится к windows.

> system("PAUSE");

зачем так писать, когда cin>>name проще

Comment: Какая программа? dev C++ что ли?

Comment: Используйте юникод

Comment: Да DEV C++ компилятор

Comment: > рекомендую использовать ТОЛЬКО ЭТОТ ВАРИАНТ он самый лучший! 

Это плохой совет. Как вы можете рекомендовать что-либо, если сами не до конца разобрались? И, как сказал предыдущий оратор, переходите на Уникод, если не можете в кодовые страницы.

@Rules, и еще... Если задаете [повторные вопросы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/70089/), убедитесь, что это действительно необходимо. Например, обязательно укажите чем не устроили ответы на предыдущую версию. Читать одно и то же - скучно. 

PS: Лично я бы перекрыл `ostream::operator<<` и `istream::operator>>` для прозрачности.

Comment: да я видел этот вариант он у меня не сработал и у тех кто оставлял комменты если и сработал то только у 3 из 10 да я ВСЁ уже перепробовал рыскал в нете 3 дня у уж поверьте мне предложенный мною вариант САМЫЙ ЛУЧШИЙ В ДАННОМ КОНТЕКСТЕ ВОПРОСА!

Comment: Вы чё совсем обалдели я выложил вопрос потом сам нашёл ответ выложил его вам !Зырьте чё вам ещё надо! Нет непонимают! Ёщё минусуют!!

Comment: @Rules Ни единого разрыва не было.

Answer (score 4):

```
SetConsoleCP(1251); // Ввод с консоли в кодировке 1251
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // Вывод на консоль в кодировке 1251. Нужно только будет изменить шрифт консоли на Lucida Console или Consolas
```

А вообще полезно пользоваться поиском по форуму, подобные вопросы задавались уже сотню раз наверное.

Comment: Говорит что не определено какой заголовочный файл подключить надо?

Comment: Я подключил <windows.h> но теперь на SetConsoleCP не ругается зато говорит что SetConsoleOutput не определено чё дклать?

Comment: Исправил, SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)

Comment: Теперь всё компилируется но получается опять абракадабра! Какие есть ещё кодировки? По перебираю может какая поможет ):

Comment: Если сделать вместо 1251 866 то получается так:

    ┬тхфшЄх ётюх шь :
    Иван
    ┬тхфшЄх ётющ ы■сшь√щ фхёхЁЄ:
    Какао
    ╙ ьхэ  хёЄ№ тъєёэ√щ Какао фы  трё, Иван.
    Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

то есть осталось только в файле правильно строки сохранять но в Dev C++ я не могу сменить кодировку и он не признаётся какую использует но блокнот говорит что кодировка ANSI что делать?

Comment: @Rules, нужно именно так как написано в ответе *и в свойствах консоли выбрать шрифт Lucida Console или Consolas*.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал такую функцию

```
#include <windows.h>

char *Rus(char *str)
{
    static char s[1024];
    CharToOem(str, s);
    return s;
}
...
std::cout << Rus("Русский текст");
```

Comment: Это сработало неправильно, посмотрите UPD к моему вопросу!