# Выводит абракадабру в консоль

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, gnu

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    string name;
    cout << "Привет! как тебя зовут?" << endl;
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Приятно познакомится, " << name << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Все вроде нормально но когда я введу имя на русском оно выведет его "Абракадаброй"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/117144/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c

Comment: @perfect может сразу  [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)?

Comment: Это еще кракозябрами называют :D

Comment: Не важно ))))))

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>                    \\ <<< попробуйте подключить это
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");      \\ <<<<< и сделать так
    string name;
    cout << "Привет! как тебя зовут?" << endl;
    cout << "Введите имя: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Приятно познакомится, " << name << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению ничего не изменилось

Comment: у меня gnu-gcc compiler mingw

Comment: а мне помогло, спасибо